# Vercelでのデプロイ時のエラー。SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, next.js

データベースとの連携の勉強でtodoアプリを作り、Vercelでのデプロイ時にエラーがでて躓いてしまったのでなにかご教授いただけると嬉しいです。
Next13, prisma, postgreSQL, railway, tailwind で作りました。

レポジトリはこちらです。
https://github.com/satoshi02198/Task-maker

ローカル環境は問題なく動いてるのですが、ビルド時に問題が起こります。
VSCODE内でビルドしてnpm run start　をしてもなにも表示されません。

ビルド時のターミナルに下記のように表示されてます。

```
    Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /                                      0 B                
0 B
+ First Load JS shared by all              82.7 kB
  ├ chunks/17-3a98e3b60f783ce7.js          80.4 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-f402105a83060ed9.js    217 B
  └ chunks/webpack-77b60a894b26ff59.js     2.04 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /404                                   179 B          81.2 kB
├ λ /api/createPosts                       0 B              81 kB
├ λ /api/deletePosts                       0 B              81 kB
├ λ /api/getPosts                          0 B              81 kB
└ λ /api/updatePosts                       0 B              81 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              81 kB
  ├ chunks/main-af00b613ec71d002.js        78.7 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-5841ab2cb3aa228d.js  192 B
  └ chunks/webpack-77b60a894b26ff59.js     2.04 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

**vercelでのエラーコード**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6160:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:478:18)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6160:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:478:18)
info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /page: /
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:415:19
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1400:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1259:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:66:29)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

page.tsx　のコードはサーバーサイドでダメでしたので、クライアントに変えてUseEffectを使ってfetchするようにしてもvercelでのデプロイはできませんでした。

```
    // "use client";
import PostForm from "../components/PostForm";
import Tasks from "../components/Tasks";
// import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

async function getPosts() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/getPosts`);
  if (!res.ok) {
    console.log(res);
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
  // const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const getPosts = async () => {
  //     try {
  //       const res = await fetch("/api/getPosts");
  //       if (res.ok) {
  //         const jsonRes = await res.json();
  //         console.log(jsonRes);
  //         setPost(jsonRes);
  //       }
  //     } catch (err) {
  //       console.log(err);
  //     }
  //   };
  //   getPosts();
  // }, []);

  const data: {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    timestamp: string;
  }[] = await getPosts();

  return (
    <div>
      <PostForm />
      <div className="sm:flex  sm:justify-center sm:items-baseline sm:flex-wrap max-w-7xl mx-auto mt-7">
        {data.reverse().map((post) => (
          <Tasks
            title={post.title}
            content={post.content}
            id={post.id}
            timestamp={post.timestamp}
          />
        ))}{" "}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```